# NullPointerException in code created with jasmin bytecode assembler

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, jasmin

This code is throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException.  I am attempting to compile a bit of code to the  jvm and this is what my compiler outputs

```
.class  public  test
.super  java/lang/Object
.field static   i  [I
.method  public static  main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
invokestatic    test/main()V
return
.limit  locals  1
.limit  stack  20
.end    method
.method  public static  main()V
.limit  locals  8
getstatic   test/i  [I
ldc 1
ldc 5
iastore
return
.limit  stack  20
.end    method
```

However it is not working an I can figure out where the error is coming from (no line number is given.)

I'm betting it is not storing the value from the global array correctly in the lines

```
getstatic   test/i  [I
ldc 1
ldc 5
iastore
```

My question is how should this compile

Comment: I don't see where you ever assign a value to `test.i`. What does the code in your source language look like? If it's something like `int[] i; void main() { i[1] = 5; }`, then your generated bytecode is correct (assuming Java-like semantics), it's just that the source code invokes an NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will compile to the Java code

```
public class Test {
    static int[] i;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main();
    }
    public static void main() {
        i[1] = 5;
    }
}
```

If you compile and run this, you'll see that it throws a NullPOinterException because nothing is creating an int array to store in `i`. You need to create an `int[]` object of dimension 2 (at least) using `newarray` to make this code work.